# Android->RecyclerView -> Moved Animation start too quickly

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

> ***I found the solution:***
>
> need call method setRemoveDuration(long duration) and set duration
>   equal to the duration of the animation( my case 4000)

I created a simple animation for RecyclerView using DefaultItemAnimator. My animation slides element which is being removed to the right side. Everything works fine except that the animation moved starts too quickly. How / where can I lock it and start (adnimationMoved) manually when slide animation finish.

[movie in youTube](https://youtu.be/8lInUGUDrdA)

**My custom Default Animator**

```
public class CustomMainDefaultAnimator extends DefaultItemAnimator {
    Context context;

    public CustomMainDefaultAnimator(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean animateRemove(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        Animation animation = new CustomAnimation(context).slideOut(4000);
        holder.itemView.startAnimation(animation);
        return super.animateRemove(holder);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean animateAdd(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        Animation animation = new CustomAnimation(context).slideIn(4000);
        holder.itemView.startAnimation(animation);
        return super.animateAdd(holder);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the method `isRunning()` of the class Animator and watch the first animation until it finish, so the method `isRunning()` returns false and then start your next animation.

Comment: but i not start move animation, it start automatically, so i think i must first block default move animation

Comment: havent try it, but as the first thing i think is to put a  postDelayed action which does the part of: holder.itemView.startAnimation(animation);
        return super.animateAdd(holder); with 4 seconds delay

Comment: i will try it asap to write a better example if i can, can you post a little bit more code so i can try the example?

Comment: i add one class and method where item is removed